# Example of Kripke's model.

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

Let's consider Kripke's model:

[image]

Why $b \Vdash (p \implies q)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Kripke semantics for intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/#KriSemForIntLog) :

> $b$ forces $(p → q)$ if, for every $b′ ≥ b$, if $b′$ forces $p$ then $b′$ forces $q$.

The only $b' \ge b$ is $b$ itself, and in $b$ both $p$ and $q$ hold.

Comment: Ok, It was pretty simple :). I didn't know a definition. Thanks :)